# Embedded Browser App for iOS / Android

Tags: android, ios, browser

I am looking for some up-front help for the design of an application which we are going to write for iOS and Adndroid.

For the most part, the UI interface will be presented via a web page within an embedded browser, which will be hosted by a device-resident 'wrapper' application. For one or two transactions, the application wrapper will need to be informed of the user's interaction with the web page.

I've done something similar in the past for Windows. With the Microsoft embedded browser control, an event is raised for navigation events, allowing the host container to handle those events. Are the embedded browsers for iOS, Android similarly constructed so that their host container can receive notification of user interactions which occur within the browser?

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Google now recommends you use [Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/) instead of WebView, especially for content external to your Android app.  Make sure you compare Custom Tabs with WebView, then determine which approach is best for your application.

---

You will want to look at [Webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

WebView is an Android UI widget that displays HTML web pages.  The stock behavior is limited, but you can add things like a custom subclass of
WebChromeClient, or POJOs that bridge the web page JavaScript to the application.  So with a little glue JS you can get user events into your app.

---

I asked our iOS guy about this and he told me iOS has a component called UIWebView.  [Here is a tutorial](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/21/tutorial-building-a-web-browser-with-uiwebview-part-1/) to give you a flavor for working with it on iOS. Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks very much for this advice. Can someone point to the equivalent approach for iOS? Thanks!